# ajaxform получает пустые data и не отправляет сообщение

Tags: php, modx

ajaxFomr успешно отправляет сообщение но сообщение не приходит
Заметил что в ответе сервера вот такая абракадабра

```
 {"success":true,"message":"\u0424\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430 
 \u0443\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e 
 \u043e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0430","data":[]}
```

И data оказывается пустой
Ответ сервера выглядит так

```
 {success: true, message: "Форма успешно отправлена", data: []}
 data: []
 message: "Форма успешно отправлена"
 success: true
```

вот сам снипет

```
[[!AjaxForm?
&snippet=`FormIt`
&form=`AjaxForm`
&emailTpl='email_tpl'
&hooks=`email,FormitSaveForm`
&emailSubject=`Заказ обратного звонка`
&emailTo=`kigat63@gmail.com`
&emailFrom = `kigat63@gmail.com`
&validate=`name:minLength=^3^,email:email:required,message:required`
&validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
&successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
]]
```

Чанк формы

```
 <div class="hide overlayForm">

 <div class="form">
      <form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post" class="ajax_form 
                        af_example">
             <h4>Закажите звонок</h4>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" value="" name='name'>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" 
                                     value="" name='phone'>
               <input type="email" placeholder="email" value="" name='email'>
                <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Шаблон сообщения

#### Сообщение

От кого:[[+name]] 
      Телефон:[[+phone]] 
      Почта:[[+email]]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У вас стоит хук FormitSaveForm, то есть модуль должен сохранять письма в админке (Приложения - FormIt). Оно что-нибудь там сохраняет?

Comment: Нет ничего не сохраняет

Comment: 1. Проверьте что уходит в POST через консоль браузера. 2. Проверьте настройки почтового ящика, от имени которого идет отправка письма.

Answer (score 1):

Т.е. ничего FormSave не сохраняет? Значит до него обработка даже не доходит.
Посмотрите, что в POST'е передается и куда, через инструменты веб-разработчика.
Поменяйте местами хуки, &hooks=`FormitSaveForm,email`, теперь должно сохранять хотя бы в первом хуке, чисто,чтобы убедиться в том, что на этапе email проблема.
Да, и проверьте, а без AjaxForm отправляет-то? https://modx.com/extras/package/quickemail